# Printing one variable based on the contents of another variable

Tags: c++, c

I have a function similar to the following that takes an integer as a parameter, and using this integer I want to to access a specific variable.
Of course, I can just casebash using the case/switch statement, or if/else, but this is far too dirty and I'm guessing there must be some form of elegant solution.

```
static unsigned char frame1[] = {...};
static unsigned char frame2[] = {...};
/*...*/
static unsigned char frame30[] = {...};

int select_frame(int frame_number){
  /* How can I use frame_number to select the correct frame variable without case/switch, if at all? */
}
```

I feel as though there could potentially be a stringstream method (or similar), though I'm not sure.
Any suggestions? I'm happy to see solutions in either of C or C++.

EDIT: I feel I should note that most of these arrays will have over 500 individual elements in them, and thus it becomes a little impractical to combine them all into one giant array. If it's possible, I'm looking for a solution that avoids this method, though I'm currently seriously considering it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what this integer has to do with selecting the correct frame? Maybe an example given an integer frame_number = 1 etc

Comment: Oh, frame_number will be a number between 1 and 30 - thus, I want to be able to do something like `sprintf(buffer, "frame%d", frame_number)` and thus the buffer array would contain the name of a valid variable (which is useless for what I need, but should be illustrative enough).

Comment: As there is no runtime reflection in C or C++, this is not possible.  The runtime has no knowledge of symbol names.  Use an array as in @Tony's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access one of the frames based on an integer, then simply put the frames into an array:

```
static unsigned char* frames[30];

frames[0] = (unsigned char*)strdup("first frame's char");
frames[1] = (unsigned char*)strdup("second frame's char");
```

Then you can directly and efficiently index to frames[i].

In C++, a more flexible approach is to use a `std::vector<std::string>` (as long as your numbers are contiguous) or even a `std::map<int, std::string>` (good if you have numbers with gaps, or want to insert/erase single elements often during runtime.

EDIT: helper function to create string literal source code from existing unsigned char arrays (off-the-top-of-my-head, tweaks may be needed):

```
void f(std::ostream& os, unsigned char* p)
{
    os << '"';
    for ( ; *p; ++p)
    {
        if (*p < ' ' || *p >= 127)
            os << '\\' << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << std::oct << *p;
        else if (*p == '\\')
            os << "\\\\";
        else
            os << *p;
    }
    os << '"';
}
```

Then just call f(frame1); f(frame2); etc...

Comment: Based on the size of the arrays, as well as the fact that they're dispersed over a few files, it's mostly an issue of difficulty - for instance, some of the arrays contain over 500 chars, so reworking them into a format acceptable for strdup is incredibly difficult. I suppose I could create a master array that has each element as a pointer to the appropriate frame* array though...

Comment: @Ben: you could use a helper function (I edited one in above), but your "master array" idea sounds easier... good thinking.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer due to its completeness, though it wasn't quite what I was looking for. It did, however, give me the idea (somehow) to use the master array pointer method. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible in C or C++. If you can, why not have a

```
static unsigned char frame[30][]
```

Comment: It's mostly the "if I can issue". The arrays themselves contain too many elements and are interspersed over too many files to be able to collect like this - easily, anyway

Comment: Would it help/make sense to collect all the frame definitions into a single, separate header file?

Comment: Oh, it'd make life easier, sure, but it's terrifically impractical (though something I'm starting to consider....)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2D array and make it a single `frames` array variable. Or, if you are ok with using `char` array then you can use `std::string`.

```
static string frames[30] = { "frame1 string", "frame2 string", ..., "frame30 string" };
int select_frame (int frame_number)
{
  string &check = frames[frame_number];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your C compiler is C99 conforming, and the array is defined outside
functions, compound literal like the following might meet the purpose.

```
static unsigned char *frames[] = {
  (unsigned char[]){ 1, 2, ... },
  (unsigned char[]){ 3, 4, ... },
  ...
};

int select_frame(int frame_number){
  ... frames[ frame_number ] ...
}
```